# how do i trigger the event for a select change from my ts file while working with reactive forms in angular 12

Tags: angular, forms, rendering, angular12

i have a reactive form where i am trying the bind the option of the form from the ts file, i have an selectchange event listener on my mat-select which is triggering when i change or select an option in the Ui , but when i try to bind an option to the mat-select the selectchange event is not triggered , can anyone help me how do i trigger that

well tried this.form.get(formcontrolname).setvalue but which is not triggering the selectchnage event.

My mat-select element-----

```
  <mat-select [formControlName]="this.getPropertyKey(property)" 
                        (selectionChange)="selectChangeDetected($event, property)" [id]="getIdProperty(property)">
```

setting form option value from ts file as ----

```
this.form.get(aliasName)?.setValue(formattedValue);
```

function triggered when matselect change event is triggered

```
selectChangeDetected(event: MatSelectChange, property: { [key: string]: string }): void {
// my data manipulations
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`(selectionChange)` only take account when you change the select using click or by keyboard. It's like if you use the event `(input)` or `(keydown)`

You need subscribe to valueChanges

```
ngOnInit()
{
   const aliasName=???
   this.form.get(aliasName).valueChanges.subscribe((res:any)=>{
       console.log(res)
   })
}
```

You can also subscribe to any change in your form

```
   this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((res:any)=>{
       console.log(res) //<--will be the value of your form
   })
```

Subscribing to form.valueChanges, you can check what "property" change using

```
this.form.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(this.form.value),
    pairwise(),
    map(([old, actual]: [any, any]) => {
      return Object.keys(old)
        .map((x) => ({ property: x, value: actual[x], old: old[x] }))
        .filter((x: any) => x.value != x.old)[0];
    })
  )
  .subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Or (if you don't want the old value)

```
this.form.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(this.form.value),
    pairwise(),
    map(([old, actual]: [any, any]) => {
      return Object.keys(old).reduce((a: any, b: string) => {
        return (
          a ||
          (actual[b] == old[b] ? null : { property: b, value: actual[b] })
        );
      }, null);
    })
  )
  .subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

**Update** if only want to "listen" some changes, we can use some like

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const controls = ['food', 'fruit'];

    merge(
      ...controls.map((x: string) =>
        (this.form.get(x)?.valueChanges || EMPTY).pipe(
          map((data: any) => ({ property: x, value: data }))
        )
      )
    ).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8shjem?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: hye this working for the first value change of form setting option but its not working for the next time a mat select value has been set from the ts file for some reason ,also any way i can trigger only mat-select-elements

Comment: @sreeK, I update the answer to control only a serie of controls and add a stackblitz (In the stackblitz works the codes, check if you have an error when you try to get the FormControl (you need subscribe after create the formGroup)